# Replace text with parsed HTML from array

Tags: jquery

I've got to replace text inside my page with content from an array.

My array contains 70 wordpais like:

```
    var wordMark = [];
    wordMark[0] = ['mytext','<b>my</b>Text'];
    wordMark[1] = ['anothertext','<b>another</b>Text'];
    wordMark[2] = ['therealtext','Therealtext'];
```

My function is following:

```
// Schriftzüge ersetzen
    function setWordMarks() {
        //for(var wordMarkI=0; wordMarkI<=wordMark.length-1; wordMarkI++){
        for(var wordMarkI=0; wordMarkI<=5; wordMarkI++){

            //alert(wordMark[wordMarkI][0]);

            $('body, body *')
                .contents()
                .filter(function() {
                    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
                        && this.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(wordMark[wordMarkI][0]) >= 0;
                }).each(function() {
                    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.toLowerCase().replace(wordMark[wordMarkI][0], wordMark[wordMarkI][1]);
                });
        };
    }
```

In general it's about to replace text-parts with the CI-compliant text.

My problem is that the b-tag ist not parsed but written in clear-text.

I hope, i coult explain my problem,
thank you very much,
Schmoozer

EDIT:
Here is the live demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var wordMark = [];
        wordMark[0] = ['mytext','<b>my</b>Text'];
        wordMark[1] = ['anothertext','<b>another</b>Text'];
        wordMark[2] = ['therealtext','therealText'];
      

// Schriftzüge ersetzen
function setWordMarks() {
     
 for(var wordMarkI=0; wordMarkI<=5; wordMarkI++){
  $('body, body *')
   .contents()
   .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
          && this.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(wordMark[wordMarkI][0]) >= 0;
  }).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.toLowerCase().replace(wordMark[wordMarkI][0], wordMark[wordMarkI][1]);
  });
  };
};  
      
      
$('span.checkTheText').click(function(){
    setWordMarks();
  });
      
});
```

```css
    .checkTheText{
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100px;
      }
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <h2>This is myText</h2>
        <div> some lorem ipsum like text including anothertext</div>
        <div>No i add TheRealText to give all three examples</div>
        
        <span class="checkTheText">Do the magic</span>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a live demo (use the 'Stack Snippet' button, the one with the pencil, to bring up an editor), or a link to a live demo elsewhere ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), for example)? That way we get a feel for what's going on.

Comment: @DavidThomas I insertet the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression for it:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var wordMark = [];
        wordMark[0] = ['mytext', '<b>my</b>Text'];
        wordMark[1] = ['anothertext', '<b>another</b>Text'];
        wordMark[2] = ['therealtext', 'Therealtext'];
        var content = $('#content').html();
        for (i=0; i < wordMark.length; i++) {
            var pattern = wordMark[i][0];
            var regExp = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
            content = content.replace(regExp, wordMark[i][1]);
        }
        $('#content').html(content);

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    This is mytext and there are anothertext so therealtext is ok.
</div>
```

Comment: problem ist not the replacing, this works fine with the code. Problem is, that the replaced text is not parsed, so my text on the page is `<b>another</b>Text` instead of **another**Text

Comment: I don't know why. Maybe you should parse that text with a parser. Anyway, mine is works.

Comment: your code works at my code to, but replaces only the first appearance of wordMark[i][0]. I should have mentioned in my request, that i have at least 3 appearances of every term in the array.

Comment: Also: it replaces the word even if it is a class-name of a div... that's why  i  wanted to use the  node-based script from my example...

Comment: But you can modify the regex, to exlude, if it's `class="wordmark_element_here"`

Comment: Hi there, sorry for my long absence. I had to work on another project :-(
I changed the pattern to 
 
`var pattern = '>'+wordMark[i][0]+'<';
var regExp = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');
content = content.replace(regExp, '>'+wordMark[i][1]+'<');`

because my replaced text is always between two tags (span or h2).